# Странное поведение react при observer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, observer, intersection-observer

Работаю с IntersectionObserver на react.
Суть следующая:

- Есть страница на которой есть список номеров.
- В каждом номере есть список тарифов
- Список тарифов ограничивается 3мя тарифами и кнопкой раскрывающей список тарифов
- При клике на кнопку в окне появляется "Плашка" Position fixed
- В случае если пользователь пролистает номер в котором он открыл плашку, и дойдет до следующего номера - плашка должна закрыться
- В случае если пользователь вернется обратно в номер с открыми тарифами в самое начало, плашка поменяет внешний вид.

Проблема в том, что код работает очень криво, закрывает плашку без причины.
Плашка открывается путем передачи id своего номера в useState.

Код обсервера:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    useEffect(() => {
        var options = {
            root: document.querySelector(".RoomRates__items"),
        };
        var callback = function (entries, observer) {
            const open = openList;
            const lines = document.querySelectorAll(".catalog-item__line");
            setTimeout(() => {
                for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                    if (entries[i].isIntersecting === true) {
                        if (openList === entries[i].target.getAttribute('id') || openList !== -1) {
                            setInfo(true)
                        } else {
                            setInfo(false)
                            setOpenList(-1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 500);
        };
        var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
        document.querySelectorAll(".catalog-item__line").forEach((el) => observer.observe(el))
    },);
```

Когда я открываю плашку в первом номере, очевидно ее id = 1, когда плашка выключена ее id = -1.
Т.е. если обсервер видит линию с id === id (Открытой плашки) то он должен поменять ее внешний вид, в обратном случае закрыть ее.

Но тут беда
Если в консоль выводить id плашки и id линии, то окажется что иногда при открытой плашке ее id равен -1, хотя нигде кроме кнопки "Открыть все тарифы" id плашки не меняется.
С чем это связано не понятно, соответственно код работает неправильно.

Comment: Зачем вы вообще используете IntersectionObserver в реакт? Изменения, которые будут вносится IntersectionObserver совершенно безразличны реакт компоненту, т.к. реакт живет своим внутренним состонием. Оттуда у вас и "странности"